# how to do android responsive design like gridview

Tags: android, responsive-design

I'm too keen to know that which layout should I use to get just like following grid design.

[image: description]

Comment: use TableLayout And Add Row Inside The Table At Run Time Where u want to Add row

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="75dp"
                 android:id="@+id/bacon"
                 android:orientation="vertical"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextureView android:id="@+id/bacon_title"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextureView android:id="@+id/bacon_time_elapsed"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <GridView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/other_stuff"
              android:numColumns="2">

    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```